# How to serialize object to JSON with Monodroid's System.Json?

Tags: json, xamarin.android

How does one turn any random object into a JSON string using Monodroid's System.Json namespace?  I see the classes there (JsonObject, JsonVlaue, etc) and I can deserialize just fine.  But serializing is eluding me.

Comment: I believe the current answer on System.Json is that it is there only for very lightweight deserialization - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5399506/using-system-json-to-convert-c-sharp-arrays-and-objects-to-a-json-string and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5026985/how-to-serialize-using-system-json-in-monotouch - so you might be better off using a port of Newtonsoft's Json.Net or ServiceStack's JSON support

Comment: @Stuart: please make this comment an answer so I can accept it and close this out.  Thanks.

Comment: :) done! Sorry it wasn't better news!

Comment: it is what it is.  I appreciate the help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe the current answer on System.Json is that it is there only for very lightweight deserialization -

- [Using System.Json to convert C# Arrays and Objects to a JSON string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5399506/using-system-json-to-convert-c-sharp-arrays-and-objects-to-a-json-string)
- [How to serialize using System.Json in MonoTouch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5026985/how-to-serialize-using-system-json-in-monotouch)

So you might be better off using a port of Newtonsoft's Json.Net or ServiceStack's JSON support

Answer (score 0):

Using this example model:

```
class MyModel
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

You can use the [DataContractJsonSerializer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.json.datacontractjsonserializer.aspx) class to serialize the object into JSON:

```
var model = new MyModel {Name = "Greg"};
var serializer = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof (MyModel));

using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
{
    serializer.WriteObject(stream, model);

    string json = Encoding.Default.GetString(stream.ToArray());

    Console.WriteLine(json);
}
```

That code will output this JSON:

```
{"Name":"Greg"}
```

If you're not tied to the built-in .NET serialization libraries, you might want to check out [Json.NET](https://github.com/ayoung/Newtonsoft.Json) or [ServiceStack](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.Text) as well.

Comment: does this actually work for you? I'm curious because other examples state that you must decorate the MyModel class as a DataContract and serializable parameters as DataMember